# Sum values based on individual column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum

Not sure if the title makes sense but I'll give this a shot.

Basically I have a report where I throw a bunch of data into a temp table and then display it on a webpage.  The totals for this report need to be a weighted average but some data in the table throws this average off.

Here's an example of the data set in the temp table

```
CustomerNo  CountryCode qJAN    rJAN    gJAN    qFEB    rFEB    gFEB
IDS1        ID          1500    0       0       1500    0       0       
ID18J       ID          8000    15      120000  8000    15      120000      
ID21        ID          3000    0       0       0       0       0       
ID22J       ID          9000    0       0       12000   0       0       
ID22S       ID          9500    0       0       0       0       0       
ID22S       ID          9500    0       0       0       0       0       
ID31S       ID          3000    0       0       0       0       0
```

Where qCOL is quantity, rCOL is rate and gCOL is gross (quantity * rate).

Now values are only to count towards the country's total if there is a quantity and rate.  The query I have been using is as follows:

```
SELECT CASE SUM(qJAN) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(gJAN) / SUM(qJAN) END AS JAN,
       CASE SUM(qFEB) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(gFEB) / SUM(qFEB) END AS FEB,
       ...
       CASE(SUM(qJAN) + SUM(qFEB) + ... )
       WHEN 0 THEN 0
       ELSE
       (SUM(gJAN) + SUM(gFEB) + ... ) / (SUM(qJAN) + SUM(qFEB) + ...) END AS TOT
FROM table
WHERE CountryCode = N'ID'
```

The above query returns the following weighted averages for JAN and FEB respectively: 3.24 and 4.90 both of which are wrong.  The correct result would be 15.00 for both.

The problem is that the above takes the quantities that have no rates into account.

I can get around this by using subqueries but what I came up with started to get out of control and will really bog things down:

```
SELECT CASE 
(SELECT SUM(qJAN) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rJAN <> 0)
WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
SUM(gJAN) / 
(SELECT SUM(qJAN) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rJAN <> 0) 
END AS JAN,
CASE 
(SELECT SUM(qFEB) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rFEB <> 0)
WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
SUM(gFEB) / 
(SELECT SUM(qFEB) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rFEB <> 0) 
END AS FEB,
...
CASE 
(
(SELECT SUM(qJAN) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rJAN <> 0) + 
(SELECT SUM(qFEB) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rFEB <> 0) + 
...
) 
WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
(SUM(gJAN) + SUM(gFEB) + ...) / 
(
(SELECT SUM(qJAN) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rJAN <> 0) + 
(SELECT SUM(qFEB) FROM table WHERE CountryCode = N'ID' AND rFEB <> 0) + ...
) END AS TOT
```

This returns the correct totals but as you can see it gets ugly fast.  All these subqueries are going to kill performance.

Is there a simpler way to get the result I'm looking for?  I feel like there must be but I'm completely brain-locking on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a PIVOT?

[Multiple PIVOTS? Need to count by Hour Per Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732445/multiple-pivots-need-to-count-by-hour-per-month)

And has a couple of examples on sqlfiddle..