# SQL Server Pivot multiple columns based on rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following two source and one destination tables in sql server 2008R2. 
How can I do pivot(s) in TSQL to get to the destination from sources? I need it urgently.

**Source Table 1: ProdType**

```
key     name
--------------
1       Magazines
2       Journals
3       Books
4       Newspaper
```

**Source Table 2: Orders**

```
seqno   ODate       Key     Qty      UnitPrice
--------------------------------------------------
1   2013-10-12      1    10       5
2   2013-10-12      4    20       3
3   2013-10-13      2    5        3
4   2013-10-14      4    50       5
5   2013-10-15      1    100      2.5
```

**Destination Table: Orders Detail**

```
                         
Odate       Magazine       Journals       Books       Newspaper
-----------------------------------------------------------------   
12/10/2013      10    5    0    0       0      0      20      3
13/10/2013       0    0    5    3       0      0       0      0
14/10/2013       0    0    0    0       0      0      50      5
15/10/2013     100    2.5  0    0       0      0       0      0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE            *qty    *unit price
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! As you can tell, I'm quite new to T-SQL (or SQL in general) and SQL Server. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello experts...Can anyone help please?

Comment: I have asked a very similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732445/multiple-pivots-need-to-count-by-hour-per-month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select
        O.ODate, P.Name,
        sum(O.Qty) as Qty,
        sum(O.UnitPrice * O.Qty) / sum(O.Qty) as UnitPrice
    from Orders as O
        inner join ProdType as P on P.Id = O.Id
    group by O.ODate, P.Name
)
select
    ODate,
    max(case when Name = 'Magazines' then Qty else 0 end) as Magazines_Qty,
    max(case when Name = 'Magazines' then UnitPrice else 0 end) as Magazines_UnitPrice,
    max(case when Name = 'Journals' then Qty else 0 end) as Journals_Qty,
    max(case when Name = 'Journals' then UnitPrice else 0 end) as Journals_UnitPrice,
    max(case when Name = 'Books' then Qty else 0 end) as Books_Qty,
    max(case when Name = 'Books' then UnitPrice else 0 end) as Books_UnitPrice,
    max(case when Name = 'Newspaper' then Qty else 0 end) as Newspaper_Qty,
    max(case when Name = 'Newspaper' then UnitPrice else 0 end) as Newspaper_UnitPrice
from cte
group by ODate
```

Or dynamic, if you want to:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt =
      isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') +
      'max(case when Name = ''' + name + ''' then Qty else 0 end) as ' + quotename(name + '_Qty') + ',' +
      'max(case when Name = ''' + name + ''' then UnitPrice else 0 end) as ' + quotename(name + '_UnitPrice')
from ProdType

select @stmt = '
    with cte as (
        select
            O.ODate, P.Name,
            sum(O.Qty) as Qty,
            sum(O.UnitPrice * O.Qty) / sum(O.Qty) as UnitPrice
        from Orders as O
            inner join ProdType as P on P.Id = O.Id
        group by O.ODate, P.Name
    )
    select
        ODate, ' + @stmt + ' from cte group by ODate'

exec dbo.sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19848/14)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks for your help. But the prod type may vary (may be less/may be more). So, I can't fix at case. Any advice to make it dynamic?

Comment: @Amy actually, there're a lot of questions about it on SO already :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Roman. It's working perfect. You save my time & help me out from stressful life. Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Yes...Actually, I look through other questions as well..But still can't find it exactly what i need. May be I'm too new in SQL..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having qty and unit price in different tables, here's a sample query for the qty destination table:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT ODate, Qty, UnitPrice, name FROM Orders INNER JOIN ProdType ON Orders.[Key] = ProdType.[Key]
)
SELECT ODate, [Magazines], [Journals], [Books], [Newspaper]  
FROM cte
PIVOT
(
SUM(Qty)
FOR name IN ([Magazines], [Journals], [Books], [Newspaper])
) AS QTYPivot
```

Comment: Thanks, Panayotis. As per my project requirement, they need to be in same table & also need to be sequence.